# Prove that every element of G is a square

Tags: abstract-algebra

An element is called a square if it can be expressed in the form $b^2 \;\exists b$.

Suppose
that $G$ is an abelian group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. If every element of $H$ is a square
and every element of $G/H$ is a square, prove that every element of $G$ is a square.

Comment: What have you done? Try to use the definitions, and use the fact that every element of $G$ is (the preimage of) an element of $G/H$ times an element of $H$.

Comment: This is a standard homework exercise, e.g., no. 37 in Gallian. It is worth searching for it here before posting. Then you can pose a more specific question.